# Loading different video resolutions on the page for different screen resolutions

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, responsive

I searshing some way to realize loading different video resolutions on the page for different browser resolutions.

On desktop devices, loads 720p video on devices with a browser less than 1200 pixels, loads 1080p video on devices with a browser equal to 1200 pixels and less than 1920 pixels, loads 4k video on devices with a browser greater than or equal to 1920 pixels. But on mobile devices it always loads vertical 720p video.

I know that media query dont work with video and this is so sad. And I started to serching some way to realize this on java script.

I found some script:

```
<!-- Add a video element -->
    <video autoplay muted playsinline></video>

    <!-- Add JavaScript code to load the appropriate video -->
    <script>
      // Define a function to load the appropriate video
      function loadVideo() {
        // Get the video element
        const videoElement = document.querySelector('video');
      
        // Check if the device is mobile
        const isMobile = /iPhone|iPad|iPod|Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
      
        // Check the browser width of the device
        const browserWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
      
        // Set the video quality based on the browser width
        let videoQuality;
        if (isMobile) {
          // Always load vertical 720p video on mobile devices
          videoQuality = '720p';
          videoElement.src = `vertical-${videoQuality}.mp4`;
        } else {
          // Load appropriate video based on browser width on stationary devices
          if (browserWidth < 1200) {
            videoQuality = '720p';
          } else if (browserWidth >= 1200 && browserWidth < 1920) {
            videoQuality = '1080p';
          } else {
            videoQuality = '4k';
          }
          videoElement.src = `horizontal-${videoQuality}.mp4`;
        }
      }
      
      // Call the loadVideo function
      loadVideo();

    </script>
```

and this code works for me, but the paths are in the script itself. But I need the make script independent of specific paths and filenames. Because I want to use this script on multiple pages and with different video codecs for different browsers. And I found some one more script:

```
<!-- Add a video element -->
    <video autoplay muted playsinline>
        
        <source data-quality="720p" src="720p.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source data-quality="1080p" src="1080p.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source data-quality="4k" src="4K.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source data-quality="720p-vertical" src="720p-vertical.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            
    </video>
    
    <!-- Add JavaScript code to load the appropriate video -->
    <script>
     const video = document.querySelector('video');
     const qualityConditions = {
       '720p': window.innerWidth < 1200,
       '1080p': window.innerWidth >= 1200 && window.innerWidth < 1920,
       '4k': window.innerWidth >= 1920,
       '720p-vertical': true
     };
     
     for (const [quality, condition] of Object.entries(qualityConditions)) {
       if (condition) {
         const source = document.querySelector(`source[data-quality="${quality}"]`);
         if (source) {
           video.appendChild(source);
           console.log(`Selected video quality: ${quality}`);
           console.log(`Selected source: ${source.src}`);
           break;
         }
       }
     }
     
     video.load();
    </script>
```

But I don't understand the behavior of this code. In the console, I can see that the script seems to correctly detect the browser's resolution and even selects the correct source, but doesn't load it. It always loads the smallest resolution of the source.

```
<video autoplay muted loop playsinline preload="auto" class="content_video">
    
    <source src="video_4K_av1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="video_4K_hevc.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="video_4K_h264.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    
    <source src="video_1080_av1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="video_1080_hevc.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="video_1080_h264.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    
    <source src="video_720_av1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="video_720_hevc.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="video_720_h264.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    
    <source src="video_720_vertical_av1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="video_720_vertical_hevc.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="video_720_vertical_h264.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    
</video>
```

Can someone help me understand what is a problem in this script? Or maybe u have some other way to realize my idea?

Comment: "I know that media query dont work with video" you can still test if a given media query would match or not using JS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia

Comment: I try. But If only I knew what I was doing. Unfortunately, my knowledge in javascript tends to zero( But the problem is that my last script correctly determines the resolution, but does not load the correct source.